¿Cómo puedo modificar los valores del resumen de una factura de Odoo 15?
Hoal a todos.
Necesito saber como hacer lo siguiente en Odoo 15.
Tengo un modelo que hereda  account.move.line.
El modelo tiene dos nuevos campos: x_actual  y x_anterior. x_anterior se introduce directamente en la factura.
Tengo otro campo que trata de sobreescribir el price_subtotal.
from odoo import models, fields, api

class AccountMoveLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move.line'

    x_actual = fields.Monetary(string="Actual", compute='_compute_x_actual', store=True)
    x_anterior = fields.Monetary(string="Anterior", store=True)
    price_subtotal = fields.Monetary(string="Líquido mes", compute='_compute_price_subtotal', store=True)

    @api.depends('quantity', 'price_unit', 'x_anterior')
    def _compute_x_actual(self):
        for line in self:
            line.x_actual = line.quantity * line.price_unit

    @api.depends('x_actual', 'price_unit', 'x_anterior')
    def _compute_price_subtotal(self):
        for line in self:
            line.price_subtotal = (line.quantity * line.price_unit) - line.x_anterior


Cuando lo ejecuto sale esto:

Quisiera que en el resumen saliera como base imponible el valor calculado de price_subtotal (10), el valor de los impuestos correctos(2,10), una suma correcta (12,10) y su correcta aplicación en los demás sitios en los que actuaría el cálculo de impuestos.
Llevo un tiempo con ello y no doy con la tecla y cuando he modifcado el tax_totals_json correctamente, solo lo veo bien antes del guardado, Si guardo, no guarda los datos que necesito guardar correctamente y guarda como si no restara nada al price_subtotal.
